# Gmail app won't scroll beyond a few days of emails on Chromebook

Tags: gmail, chromebook

I'm trying to scroll back to an email from last week in the gmail app on my Chromebook and it just stops at a certain point and won't scroll back any farther.  Has there been a new feature introduced in a recent update that requires some setting to retrieve more than a certain number of emails?